# Objective c websockets for desktop application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

All of the Objective c websocket libraries that I've found seem to be specific for iOS and give linking problems when I try to use them in my desktop app.

I've tried:

http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient

https://github.com/esad/zimt

Are there Objective c libraries that work for desktop apps? Alternatively how difficult would it be to modify zimt to work on the desktop?

EDIT: I ended up using: https://github.com/erichocean/cocoa-websocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried zimt and it was trivial to integrate into a test OS X project.  I followed the installation instructions, then set the project to be Mac rather than iOS and Intel rather than ARM.

If you are having difficulty getting it working, then submit that as a question, including any error messages you get and any incorrect behaviour you see.

Comment: your instructions got me much further - However when I add #import "ZTWebSocket.h" it autocomplets, but then says "file not found". Same goes for when I try to include "#import "Zimt/Zimt.h"" (like in the sample code).

Comment: It sounds like you didn't follow the installation instructions.  Did you add the include path like they tell you to?